# Cannot get the value of appsettings.json in Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have this in my "appsettings.json"

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AlprReport": {
    "ConnectionAddress": "http://192.168.100.37:81/alprreport/cashdeclaration"
  }
```

I tried getting it in my Razor as so:

```
public RazorComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] IConfiguration configuration;
    
    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        var result = configuration.GetSection("AlprReport:ConnectionAddress").Value
    }
}
```

I always get null value on result. I tried getting it from my "Program.cs" using this:

```
var alprReport = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AlprReport:ConnectionAddress").Value;
```

Still I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which directory is your appsettings.json file in?

Answer (score 7):

Check the path where your `appsettings.json` is located. Since it's Blazor WASM, it should be inside the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: I am at the development mode so I should be able to get the appsettings.json outside the wwwroot folder.

Comment: Not really. It should be inside wwwroot like @Raffy said.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a blazor wasm application hosted on asp.net core server. In this scenario you actually have two `appsettings.json` files, one for the server application and one for the client. You are probably trying to access server's `appsettings.json` from your client but you can't access server files like that. For the client you have to create a separate appsettings.json file located inside `wwwroot` folder as you can also see in the documentaion:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

If you want to access server's appsettings from client you have to expose it via an api (bad idea if you store sensitive data in configuration). Example:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class InfoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public InfoController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("config")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetConfiguration()
    {
        var result = _configuration["AlprReport:ConnectionAddress"];
  
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Then in `Program.cs`, modify the existing `HttpClient` service registration to use the client to read the file:

```cs
var http = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
};

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => http);

using var response = await http.GetAsync("api/info/config");
using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(stream);
```

[Blazor App settings configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#app-settings-configuration)

Comment: I have wwwroot\appSettings.json in my Blazer WebAssembly Client project and cannot read values from wwwroot\appSettings.json in Program.cs ..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GetConnectionString`:

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionAddress": "http://192.168.100.37:81/alprreport/cashdeclaration"
  }
  // then the same code with injection but use instead `GetConnectionString`
  var result = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionAddress");
```

Or continue your way and change your code to :

`configuration.GetSection("AlprReport")["ConnectionAddress"]`

because GetSection is a key value method!

Comment: Or simply `var result = configuration["AlprReport:ConnectionAddress"];`